# Why some exe files(like PsExec.exe) cannot be moved to another folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, psexec

I have downloaded the Sysinternals Suite from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite

After unzipping it, I want to put all the files into a new place, but the following 4 files cannot be copied to anywhere(like E:/):

**PsExec.exe

PsExec64.exe

pskill.exe

pskill64.exe**

The Windows 10 is always asking for"You'll need to provide administrator permission to copy this file".
But I am the administrator and after I click "Continue", it always says:
"You need permission to perform this action"
So that I cannot copy the file.
I tried with running Powershell as an administrator, but also failed.

Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Some anti-virus software blocks these files. Where are the files currently at and where are you trying to copy them to? Provide actual path names.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thank you very much! That's the case. I have installed sophos and it prevents me from copying to anyplace in my pc.

Answer (score 1):

As @Appleoddity pointed out, it is because of the anti-virus software...

I have installed Sophos but it gives no warning/message about that I cannot move the files.

The solution is to authorize these files in Sophos.